# Docker mongo image always save the data inside /data/db directory

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using **[docker image for mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)**. I changed the directory where I want to save my data inside the mongo.conf file:

```
dbpath=/mnt/sda1/data/db/
```

Also I am using docker-compose to create my development environment:

```
mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports:
   - 27017:27017
  volumes:
   - $HOME/Desktop/development/mongo/data/:/mnt/sda1/data/db/
   - $HOME/Desktop/mongo/config/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf.orig
  command: mongod --smallfiles
```

When I go inside my mongo container and I check the **/mnt/sda1/data/db** directoy, it is empty and then go to **/data/db** and the data is here.

I don't understand why the data isn't inside the directory **/mnt/sda1/data/db** is I defined it has the **dbpath** for mongo configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are naming the config file `/etc/mongod.conf.orig` inside the container. You probably should name it `/etc/mongod.conf`.

Also, unlike `docker run`, you can use relative path for the `volume` option in your `docker-compose.yml` file and don't have to use `$HOME`.

Comment: My problem is about why if I changed the dbpath in mongo.conf file and share it to my docker using a volume, but the data is always saved inside /data/db when I set /mnt/sda1/data/db. How do I change this behaviour ?

Comment: Sorry, my guess was that the config file was not found because of an error in the `volume` definition. I updated the answer.